# How to use a 4x4 membrane keypad with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am creating a gui that will compare the user's input for passcode with the database. Is there a way to use a 4x4 membrane keypad with tkinter by having the user's input be shown in on the frame using this code for frames as reference?

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

**For Example:** Say a user wants to input "123A", use "#" as confirmation, and "*" to delete/reset, how can I get it so that every input is shown on the frame?

***EDIT*** This is the code I used to confirm that the keypad works by having a lock disengage when the pin is correct.

````
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(relay, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(relay, 0)

# These are the GPIO pin numbers where the
# lines of the keypad matrix are connected
L1 = 5
L2 = 6
L3 = 13
L4 = 19

# These are the four columns
C1 = 12
C2 = 16
C3 = 20
C4 = 21

# The GPIO pin of the column of the key that is currently
# being held down or -1 if no key is pressed
keypadPressed = -1

secretCode = "4789"
input = ""

# Setup GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(L1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(L2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(L3, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(L4, GPIO.OUT)

# Use the internal pull-down resistors
GPIO.setup(C1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(C2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(C3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(C4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

# This callback registers the key that was pressed
# if no other key is currently pressed
def keypadCallback(channel):
    global keypadPressed
    if keypadPressed == -1:
        keypadPressed = channel

# Detect the rising edges on the column lines of the
# keypad. This way, we can detect if the user presses
# a button when we send a pulse.
GPIO.add_event_detect(C1, GPIO.RISING, callback=keypadCallback)
GPIO.add_event_detect(C2, GPIO.RISING, callback=keypadCallback)
GPIO.add_event_detect(C3, GPIO.RISING, callback=keypadCallback)
GPIO.add_event_detect(C4, GPIO.RISING, callback=keypadCallback)

# Sets all lines to a specific state. This is a helper
# for detecting when the user releases a button
def setAllLines(state):
    GPIO.output(L1, state)
    GPIO.output(L2, state)
    GPIO.output(L3, state)
    GPIO.output(L4, state)

def checkSpecialKeys():
    global input
    pressed = False

    GPIO.output(L3, GPIO.HIGH)

    if (GPIO.input(C1) == 1):
        print("Input reset!")
        pressed = True

    GPIO.output(L3, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(L1, GPIO.HIGH)

    if (not pressed and GPIO.input(C3) == 1):
        if input == secretCode:
            print("Code correct! Door is unlocking")
            
            #Unlocking the door
            GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(5)
            
            #Locking the door again automatically
            print("Door is now locked")
            GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)

        else:
            print("Incorrect code!")
            # TODO: Sound an alarm, send an email, etc.
        pressed = True

    GPIO.output(L3, GPIO.LOW)

    if pressed:
        input = ""

    return pressed

# reads the columns and appends the value, that corresponds
# to the button, to a variable
def readLine(line, characters):
    global input
    # We have to send a pulse on each line to
    # detect button presses
    GPIO.output(line, GPIO.HIGH)
    if(GPIO.input(C1) == 1):
        input = input + characters[0]
    if(GPIO.input(C2) == 1):
        input = input + characters[1]
    if(GPIO.input(C3) == 1):
        input = input + characters[2]
    if(GPIO.input(C4) == 1):
        input = input + characters[3]
    GPIO.output(line, GPIO.LOW)

try:
    while True:
        # If a button was previously pressed,
        # check, whether the user has released it yet
        if keypadPressed != -1:
            setAllLines(GPIO.HIGH)
            if GPIO.input(keypadPressed) == 0:
                keypadPressed = -1
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        # Otherwise, just read the input
        else:
            if not checkSpecialKeys():
                readLine(L1, ["1","2","3","A"])
                readLine(L2, ["4","5","6","B"])
                readLine(L3, ["7","8","9","C"])
                readLine(L4, ["*","0","#","D"])
                time.sleep(0.1)
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nApplication stopped!") ```
````

Comment: Yes. It is possible to use a membrane keypad with the raspberry pi and tkinter. What attempt have you made to read the GPIO pins to detect which buttons have been pressed? Have you wired the keypad up?

Comment: Yes I already have a working file that reads the GPIO pins to detect which button was pressed, tested it with a random pin, and configured it so that “#” is enter and “*” is reset. I’m just confused as to how I can begin using the membrane with tkinter.

Comment: Then I suggest you post that code too. The example code you have given so far is very generic (and copied seemingly directly from another SO question) and doesn't relate to your question. I would have the keypress code running in a seperate thread and when a key is pressed add they key to a queue. Periodically (using the tkinter `.after` method), I'd read this queue and update the gui accordingly.

Comment: Another method would be to use something like pyinput to map the keypad buttons to a "virtual keyboard"

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I added the code I used for the keypad.